# How to have elements in an array according to another array swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3

So I have an array which has 5 elements for eg. [a, b, c, d, e]. To this array, I can add items or I can delete items. Now, I want another array which should have number of zeroes according to the first array.

For e.g. is the first array contains [a, b, c, d, e], then I want the other array to be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. But if I remove an element and make the first array [a, b, c, d] then the second array should be [0, 0, 0, 0] and if I add an element and make the array [a, b, c, d, e, f] then the second array should be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] and so forth.

Is there any way to do this in swift 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code when you add or remove elements -

```
let values = ["a","b","c","d"]
let valuesZeroArray = values.map {_ in 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Array's initializer that takes a repeating value and a number.

```
let values = ["a","b","c","d"]
let zeroes = Array(repeating: 0, count: values.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = ["a","b","c","d"]
var zeroes = values.map {_ in 0}
print(values)
print(zeroes)
values.append("e")
values.append("f")
values.remove(at: 3)
print(values)
for _ in values {
    zeroes = values.map {_ in 0}
}
print(zeroes)
```